# iOS event bus library with event objects?

Tags: ios, swift, events

We've used greenrobot's [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library extensively in Android development, and we're looking for something similar for iOS. It looks like a sort of event bus is already built in in the form of [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/), as well as quite a few third-party solutions that are essentially wrappers for this functionality with some added features for convenience.

However, we're rather accustomed to the concept of events being discrete objects with clearly defined member variables, with the additional benefit of polymorphism from being object-oriented. Most iOS libraries I've found so far have you passing in an arbitrary event name and an arbitrary bundle of data, which is a little too loosey-goosey for our purposes.

The only example of the object-oriented design I've found so far is [Tolo](http://genzeb.github.io/tolo/), which looks great at first glance, but hasn't been updated in about three years, save for some minor documentation details. Also, given its age, it's still written in Objective-C, which could lead to some difficulties if we need to look under the hood at some point (we're pretty committed to Swift).

Are there any other options I haven't come across yet?

Answer (score 0):

No reason why you cannot create a specific class that you pass as the object in `NSNotificationCenter`. Its true that many examples are lazy in this respect, obj-c is traditionally fairly loosely typed which probably explains this.

Its also fairly common (in projects bigger than online tutorials) to use a constant of some sort as the event name, either a class constant or a `#define` if using obj-c.

Comment: Creating a specific class to pass as the object isn't sufficient, as the object (or the contents of the object) will need to vary depending on the type of event it is. Basically, we just want a strict enforcement between event name and type of data expected. I've tried handling this with generics and associated types, but it's just not coming together for me.

Comment: You always can put kind a data type id in some variable in general object and than just use it to pick relevant handling. What you think? btw if you found EventBus port to swift please post link here.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in 2017+ interested in this, I wrote this thing ages ago:
https://github.com/MooseMagnet/DeliciousPubSub

It offers strongly-typed pub-sub.
Under the hood it still uses strings as a key (just uses the name of the type) but you get compile-time goodness...

I left it sitting for a while under the assumption no one was using it, but recently received a PR from someone who had updated it for Swift 3. Wow, such OSS.